# Adding exit voice command to Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

Is there a simple way to add a voice trigger to close an immersion app for google glass? I'm currently learning to write code for glass and have a basic hello world app and would like to add a voice trigger to exit back to the home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way, just go the standard routine. Add a voice trigger for a close option in your menu and call `finish()` on execution.